# Centralized Items Horizontal ListView

Tags: android, horizontallist

I want to do some thing like this.

[image]
[image]

There I have Horizontal List View.

```
<com.sample.HorizontalListView
            android:id="@+id/hlist_collection_items"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/horizontal_list_collection_image_height"
            android:background="#44aaaaaa"
            android:divider="#44aaaaaa"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"                
            android:fadingEdgeLength="5dp"
            custom:dividerWidth="2dp" />
```

What I have to do more? for make it centralized items.??
My ListItem XML is below.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/product_image_view_1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/horizontal_list_collection_item_image_height"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/horizontal_list_collection_item_image_height"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:src="@drawable/loading_image"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have to make it centralized item. there items aligned Left.

Comment: http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34 This might help

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to make the listview in central?

try :

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
```

Or if you want to centralize what **inside** the `listview` :

```
android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
```

Put it on your custom adapter's `row.xml` (The one you use to inflate your custom adapter)

UPDATE

Try this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" //change to wrap_content
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center" >
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/product_image_view_1"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/horizontal_list_collection_item_image_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/horizontal_list_collection_item_image_height"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center" //add this
        android:src="@drawable/loading_image"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

Comment: i have width match_parent. there doesn't mean anything like layout_gravity as center_horizontal.

Comment: Ups, my bad. Have you tried to centralize in the row.xml?